# How can I prevent a table not having references pointing to it?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE s_users (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username text
);

CREATE TABLE s_projects (
    project_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    projectname text
);

CREATE TYPE s_MEMBERSHIP_TIER AS ENUM ('pending', 'member', 'admin');

CREATE TABLE s_memberships (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    project_id INT NOT NULL,
    membership_tier MEMBERSHIP_TIER,
    CONSTRAINT s_one_membership_type
        UNIQUE(user_id, project_id)
);
```

I want to ensure that it will be impossible to get to a situation where:
(1) a membership refers to a project or user that doesn't exist, and
(2) a project is without members.

I think I can achieve (1) by changing the first rows in `CREATE TABLE s_memberships (` to

```
    user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES s_users ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    project_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES s_projects ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

But how can I avoid a project without members?

I.e.

```
INSERT INTO s_users (username) values ('mickey');
INSERT INTO s_users (username) values ('donald');
INSERT INTO s_projects (projectname) values ('p1');  -- this should not succeed to create a project without any members.
```

I've tried something like:

```
ALTER TABLE s_projects ADD CONSTRAINT pid FOREIGN KEY(project_id) REFERENCES s_memberships(project_id);
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "s_memberships"
```

Is there some other constraint I can add? Or, alternatively, is there a better way to organise my tables?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options I can think of:

1. You create a foreign key from `s_projects` to `s_membership` that identifies a "special member" (project leader?) that must always be there.
2. You have a column `member_count` in `s_project` that is maintained by a trigger on `s_membership`, so that it always contains the number of members in that project. Then you place a check constraint on `s_project` that forces that number to be greater than 0.

Comment: The "special member" idea seems appealing, though it seems to me that I'd also need deferrables with this solution.

Comment: Yes, either deferrable constraints, or you use a `WITH` clause to insert into both tables in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

A project without members is quite tricky.  You can't insert a membership unless there is a project.  And you want to requite that a project has members.

One solution is to use a *deferrable* constraint so you can insert both rows at the same time.  You can alter the table to defer the constraint check, insert the rows, and then undefer the constraint.

However, I prefer other solutions.

One is to include a member count in `projects`.  Maintaining this requires triggers -- which are yucky -- but you can then get "active" projects using a `where` clause:  `where num_members > 0`.

Or just create a view:

```
create view active_projects as
    select p.*
    from projects p
    where exists (select 1 from memberships m where m.project_id = p.project_id);
```

In other words, these solutions allow "inactive" projects, but then just hide them when desired.